# Is google drive picker api support delete files and upload folder?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-picker

I was going through the google drive picker api docs, I didn't find the proper solution to handle the delete files/folder(s) through the picker.

I just wanted to confirm that google picker support the delete functionality or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Drive Picker API**

It is a limitation or feature missing itself from the Drive picker. It is generally designed or used to view data that is available to be accessed, deleted files would not be considered as available data to be used, it would require the manual restoration process.

As an alternative or request for either documentation or feature, you should be able to open an Issue tracker:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106

**References:**

- https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview

Comment: @ChandraPrashadmishra if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74691970/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)