# Google apps Script to find cell containing text in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script to find text in a cell and go to that cell. Having done that I want to move to the right in the sheet. The text that it should find is in cell G1. The contents of G1 will change.

This:

```
function FindProduct () {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Stock'), true);
var textToFind = "20329";
var finder = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().createTextFinder(textToFind);
finder.findNext().activate()
};
```

Finds the text "20329" no problem but I cannot get it to look at G1 to get the text to find.

This is what I tried

```
function FindProduct () {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Stock'), true);
var textToFind = ('g1');
var finder = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().createTextFinder(textToFind);
finder.findNext().activate()
};
```

G1 contains 20329. This does not work but instead goes to cell G55 in another sheet called "Customers".

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: How are you executing this script? onEdit? menu option?

Comment: Based in `The text that it should find is in cell G1`, will the text that you are looking for always be in cell G1? Now, based in `Having done that I want to move to the right in the sheet.` do you mean that you want to move that text to the cell on the right? If so, do you want to keep every single value that you move to the right or do you want to just move the text once and then on the next run can the information be deleted?

Comment: I'm starting it from a custom menu. After it has found the cell with the text in it I want to select a cell 17 columns to the right then right again to the last cell with text in it, move one more to the right (to an empty cell) and then paste the contents of some different cells in to the next 3 cells to the right. Eg if it finds the text in A345 (it will always be col A) move 11 to the right to R345 skip to the right of any number of cells that are filled to the 1st empty one and then paste in 3 cells to the right of that say U345 to W345.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the value will always be in column A, then you want to move that value and check the next empty space after 11 columns to the right and past that value in the next 3 empty cells, correct? For example, lets assume R345 is not empty and the next empty cell is T345, so you want to paste that value in T345-V345, and then delete the original value in column A, correct? @BenC

Comment: Almost right, I don't want to move the value in Col A, that is the reference. The sheet I am looking for the ref in contains my customer details, name address phone email vehicle and their vehicle details plus work carried out for them. Some of all may or may not be present for all customers. If we jump 17 then it will get to the end of all their data and then the next jump will take us to the end of the last record of work done ready to paste in the latest repairs (taken from another sheet) Hope I made it clearer! Thanks for looking at it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Testing')
      .addItem('Find Customer', 'FindCustomer')
      .addToUi();

};

function FindCustomer () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Stock");
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var textToFind = ss.getRange('G1').getValue();

  for(var x=0;x<data.length; x++)
  {
    if(data[x][0]==textToFind)
    {
      break;
    }
  }

  var r = ss.getRange("A"+`${x+1}`);
  var i=0;

  while(r.offset(0, 17+i).getValue()!="")
  {
    i++;
  }
  for(var y=0; y<3; y++)
  {
    r.offset(0, 17+i+y).setValue(textToFind);
  }

}
```

#### References:

- [offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)

Comment: - Fernando Lara Thanks for that. No it didn't work, wherever I put the active cell to start with, it moves to a cell containing "NG14 5FR". If I move that text to another cell, it will go to the new position.

Comment: @BenC I think it would be better if you could provide a sample sheet with some dummy data so we can better understand the behavior and how the script would work with that data.

Comment: Link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZuoE1BV3nzJLwLPMdS43mUvLJ8KBlDfS1GpMWYpy2J0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly the value you want to search will always be in G1 but you will search it in column A, correct?

Comment: Yes, or the source might be better in A1. Thanks

Comment: @BenC I have edited my answer. Please let me know if the new script works as expected.

Comment: No it didn't work I got the message TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getDataRange')

Comment: Don't worry you have spent too much time on it already, but Many Thanks for trying

Comment: Did you rename your testing sheet to "Stock" as you have it in your main sheet according to your main code? @BenC I have just tested and it works for me after renaming it. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: No I hadn't noticed that. Changed it and it works! Many Thanks for your help. Regards Ben

Comment: @BenC if this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. How to accept answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74691970/17926478
https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Ricardo Jose Velasquez Cruz
Sorry I cannot see an accept button

Comment: @BenC you can try the [following steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or you can also [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the question if it was useful to you. Let me know if that helps!